# Get nginx location wildcard inside location block?

Tags: nginx, php, routing, rewrite, php-fpm

I am trying to set up an API where I can access API "foobar" through the URL `http://my-apis.com/foobar/route`. This is what I have so far:

```
location ~ ^/foobar(/.*)$ {
    root /var/www/mysite/foobar/public;

    ... more fastcgi stuff ...

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php$1;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

The API is routing to a Slim framework application and currently it successfully routes to the correct index.php, showing an nginx 404/403 whenever the URL does not start with `/foobar`. However the route passed to Slim (which looks like it's represented by $1 on line 6) is still the full `/foobar/route`. This means I have to append all all my Slim routes with `/foobar`, which, although I can use a Slim group, is still a pain. I would like to be able to pass just the `/route` bit to Slim.

Is there a way I can extract just the wildcard-matched bit of the location directive? Since $1 gives the full route. Alternatively I might be able to do this with some kind of rewrite, but I don't know enough about Slim.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not re-post questions you have already asked.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen This is not a repost.... It's a different question that has followed on from one I asked previously, but the last one is still relevant so I wanted to keep them separate. Forgive me for not polluting the site. Please read questions properly.

Answer (score 1):

`SCRIPT_FILENAME` is the path to the script and not the original URI. Scripts pick up the path info from `PATH_INFO` or by decoding the original URI (using `REQUEST_URI`).

This might work for you:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1;
```